# Get data by demand when doing COM Enumeration using ATL

Tags: c++, com, atl

It is relative easy to do a [Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x416d0xc.aspx) in C++ ATL using the [CComEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/cpp/atl/reference/ccomenum-class) / [CComEnumOnSTL](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/cpp/atl/reference/ccomenumonstl-class) clases.

The problem with these classes is that you have to store the data in a array or list before the iteration. That is not possible for us as it is quite time-consuming to retrieve all data for the lists, and therefore we do not want to get out more than necessary from the underlying system. Moreover, the consumer of our COM interface usually does not iterate the entire lists.

The idea is that the implementation of the [IEnumXXXX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms680089.aspx) interface has a pointer for current entry in the list. If the consumer wants the next entry in the list, it do a search for the next entry and returns the content of that entry (yes, the underlying system could be improved on many levels, but now is it as it is)

So my question is if there is any good way to implement [IEnumXXXX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms680089.aspx) using ATL,  where the complete array is not known from the beginning of the iteration. Or do I have to implement an [IEnumXXXX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms680089.aspx) for each list being handled (quite a few lists)

Comment: `CComEnumOnSTL` doesn't actually require an STL collection specifically, just a class that pretends well enough to be one. You can write your own iterator class a la `istream_iterator` that manufactures elements on the fly, and a "collection" class whose `begin()` and `end()` would produce those iterators.

Comment: Alternatively, just take the source code of `IEnumOnSTLImpl` or `CComEnumImpl`, and write your own similar implementation tuned to taste. `IEnumXXX` is not really complicated.